# Which import do i require to make use of hashrouter in KotlinJS React App

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, kotlin-js

I'm bootstrapping a KotlinJS + React application using the following steps:

```
npm install -g create-react-kotlin-app
create-react-kotlin-app frontend
cd frontend
npm install kotlinx-coroutines-core
npm install @jetbrains/kotlin-react-router-dom
```

This gives me a basic KotlinJS + React app

In `package.json` i can see my router import

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@jetbrains/kotlin-react-router-dom": "^4.3.1-pre.61",
    "kotlinx-coroutines-core": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts-kotlin": "3.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-kotlin start",
    "build": "react-scripts-kotlin build",
    "eject": "react-scripts-kotlin eject",
    "gen-idea-libs": "react-scripts-kotlin gen-idea-libs",
    "get-types": "react-scripts-kotlin get-types --dest=src/types",
    "postinstall": "npm run gen-idea-libs"
  }
}
```

The examples on several sites show something like this, but not which imports to use

```
class RootComponent : RComponent<RProps, RState>() {
    override fun RBuilder.render() {
        hashRouter { // or "browserRouter"
            switch {
                route("/", IndexComponent::class, exact = true)
                route("/login", strict = true) {
                    login(providers = listOf("plain", "facebook"))
                    a(href = "#/") {
                        +"Back"
                    }
                }
                route<IdProps>("/user/:id") { props ->
                    div {
                        +"User id: ${props.match.params.id}"
                    }
                }
                redirect(from = "/redirect", to = "/redirected")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not defining `hashRouter` via an import causes a

```
src/app/App.kt:11:3: error: unresolved reference: hashRouter
                hashRouter {
  ^
```

I'm trying Ctrl + Space, but autocomplete isn't useful at all.

Which import am i missing?

Comment: create-react-kotlin-app is limited to configurations, try using kotlin/js with gradle and the frontend plugin instead

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and managed to fix it using the following steps.

Within the application directory, install the following in order.

1. `npm i @jetbrains/kotlin-react-router-dom`
2. `npm run gen-idea-libs`

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `react-router-dom"` as well in your dependencies.